# Как связать checkbox с multiselect в Vue?

Tags: vue.js, checkbox

Интересует вопрос как связать checkbox с multiselect на Vue.
Например, в multiselect есть определенные категории. Эти же категории повторяются в checkbox. Нужно при активном checkbox сделать активный элемент в списке.
Должно получиться как на фото которое прикрепил.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Код на [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/abuv5pnz/2/).

```
let vm = new Vue({
components: {
                Multiselect: VueMultiselect.default
            },
            data() {
                return {
                    listCategory: ['Категория 1', 'Категория 2', 'Категория 3', 'Категория 4', 'Категория 5', 'Категория 6', 'Категория 7'],
                    valueCategory: [],
                }
            },
            el: "#main-app",
        })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Суть в том чтобы вывести через v-for чекбоксы и поставить динамический атрибут checked, который true если значение чекбокса содержите в массиве multiselect.

Запустить можно тут: https://jsfiddle.net/abuv5pnz/32/

```
<div id="main-app">
  <multiselect v-model="valueCategory" :options="listCategory" :multiple="true" values="category" placeholder="Категория" class="category-dropdown">
     <span slot="noResult">Oops! No elements found. Consider changing the search query.</span>
  </multiselect>

  <ul>
    <li v-for="cat of listCategory">
      <input type="checkbox" :id="'category-' + cat" :value="cat" :checked="valueCategory.includes(cat)">
      <label :for="'category-' + cat">{{ cat }}</label>
    </li>
  </ul>
  </div>
```

**update:**

Добавил что если выбираешь чекбокс то выбирается и в multiselect. Суть в том что на чекбоксе есть обработчик `@input="setCheckbox($event, cat)"`

Если чекбокс выбирается, то добавить элемент в valueCategory иначе удалить от туда.

```
        methods: {
            setCheckbox (event, el) {
            if (event.target.checked)
                this.valueCategory.push(el)
            else
                this.valueCategory = this.valueCategory.filter(i => i !== el)
          }
        },
```

Comment: Илья, спасибо за ваш ответ. Подскажите еще пожалуйста как для каждой категории задать уникальную картинку?

Comment: @Endu не совсем понимаю что за картинка, можно код?

Comment: спасибо что нашли время отписать мне. Тут код - [ссылка](https://jsfiddle.net/urqog2nc/6/) .
Я к категориям добавил 2 изменении (иконки и фотографии). Теперь когда удалять из перечня отмеченные категории (в multiselect) то оно их наоборот дублирует. И еще вопрос, относительно второго multiselect. В коде написал комментарий относительно него. Если будет время то поправьте пожалуйста. Хорошего Вам дня, и спасибо за помощь

Comment: @Endu у Вас там в valueCategory попадает весь объект, а не строка знечение из category которое Вы еще указали в values(я смотрел API этой библиотеки и не нашел там такого параметра) Поэтому наверное и удаляет криво. Второй вопрос решил: https://jsfiddle.net/urqog2nc/8/

Comment: очень Вам благодарен. Хорошего вечера!